# What's the difference between ErrorCode and MessagingErrorCode?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Take, for example, `FirebaseMessagingException` as it's thrown by `FirebaseMessaging#sendAll`. It has a `MessagingErrorCode` as nullable parameter and an `ErrorCode` as non-nullable.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/error-handling#checking-error-codes), certain error codes can be retried, e.g. `ErrorCode.UNAVAILABLE`.

The documentation does not mention that there is also `MessagingErrorCode.UNAVAILABLE`, for example.

So, what's the difference?